# Jquery media queries isn't apply without refreshing

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have following code in my page. Background color works perfectly. But I have to refresh to see the change regarding **li**. If I don't refresh, **li** has previous effect. Such as in windows screen smaller 500 px, **li** is shown without clicking.

```
function myFunction() {
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('body').css('background', 'black');
    $("nav").click(function() {
      $("li").toggle('slow');
    });
  } else {
    $('body').css('background', 'blue');
    $("li").show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code as a function and call it on onload and on window resize like below

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //your function
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  //your function
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Prons, no thing changed putting in onload, still same problem

Comment: call the function in $(window).resize also. So when ever the window size changes, the function will trigger and check the window width. Based on the condition status, it will apply background.

$(window).load is used to do the same check on page load.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger it also on resize, so if you resize the window it will trigger the queries like

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
  //your code goes here
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('body').css('background', 'black');
    $("nav").click(function() {
      $("li").toggle('slow');
    });
  } else {
    $('body').css('background', 'blue');
    $("li").show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Traver, I tried using your idea, but still same problem.

Comment: So mh. I understood ur question wrong i guess. But cant you just do this with css queries

Answer (score 1):

```
$("nav").click(function() {
  $("li").toggle('slow');
});

function myFunction() {
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'black');
  } else {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
    $("li").show();
  }
}
```

1. Instead of `background`, you should `background-color`
2. Secondly, you can have `click` outside on the function rather than defining it inside.
3. Assuming, `myFunction` is triggered/called on `resize` or `load`